# SQLite random database connection crash

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am programming a database export solution to convert a database. It is exporting and processing some hundred gigabytes of data in a multithreaded environment. All threads work in their own environment with own connections, but for orchestrating the export uses a sqlite "lookup" database that is used by all threads to distribute work and encode a specific field to a new id. This happens quite rarely (once every 50k rows exported) so it should not really slow the process even if locks are used.

For some reason about every 10-15min this lookup database throws an exception "could not open database" with errorcode 14. The exception randomly occurs on any of the ExecuteReader() methods.  I tried to lock all methods accessing this database but still it crashes every 10-15min. Why? Actually when I just press on Resume in debugging mode everything works again, seems to be a temporary problem.

ExecuteLookup() is called by "main" exporting thread repeatedly.

DBQueryLookupDb() is called by any of the worker threads. (Something like INSERT INTO progress ...)

```
// using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite


  private long ExecuteLookup(string value)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                using (var cmd = GetSelectLookupCmd()) // "SELECT id,original FROM lookup_id WHERE original = @original", parameter is added, tried to re-use this command but same problem
                {
                    cmd.Parameters["@original"].Value = value;
                    using (var res = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (res.Read())
                        {
                            return res.GetInt64(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
                using (var cmd = GetInsertLookupCmd()) // INSERT INTO ...;SELECT last_insert_rowid();
                {


                    cmd.Parameters["@original"].Value = value;
                    using (var res = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {

                        if (res.Read())
                        {
                            return res.GetInt64(0);
                        }
                        else { throw new Exception("Unexpected fail on lookup insert"); }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public void DBQueryLookupDb(string sql)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                using (SqliteCommand c = new SqliteCommand())
                {
                    c.Connection = lookupDb;
                    c.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                    c.CommandText = sql;
                    c.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

"PRAGMA JOURNAL_MODE ='PERSIST'" resolves the problem. TRUNCATE may work too. It may be a sync problem coming from the network drive (Sqlite deletes the journal and immediatley creates a new one before the network drive is ready again)